# What do Shastra say about building Temples outside of India?

Tags: vedas, agamas, vedic-rituals, reference-request, spiritual-level

I want to build a Temple in Europe. Which Shastra would I refer to? Vastu, Agama or something else?

Moreover I want to know what every geographical places carry as Karma Veda and if and how that influences the construction of that Temple.

Can I convert with pujas those influences?

[Obviously under Sannyasins, GuRus, Experts Guidance. Or, they must do and I just participate or assist or be a spectator, etc]

Which procedures are more indicated?

How the whole process works?

Comment: You need to ask the authorities running a HIndu temple in Europe.

Comment: 'temples' are a recent construct in Hinduism, of only thousands of years. They are not addressed in scriptures.

Comment: Temples, Temple construction related rules and Vastu are part and parcel of Agamas. You must increase your knowledge about Hinduism before downvoting valid questions. Hinduism is not just about those 3 books. @SwamiVishwananda

Comment: I agree with Rickross, and partially with @SwamiVishwananda. It is true that Bhagavan gives prominence to Archa (murti) form in kali yug (out of the 5 forms of para, vyuha, vibhava, antaryami and archa), hence why temples are more prevalent today than in earlier yugas. Still, saying temples not mentioned in scriptures does not make any sense. There are different scriptures and paths that are important for different Yugas. Vaikhanasa/Pancharatra agamas clearly lay down temple & ritual details.

Comment: Thank you very much @ram Furthermore I want to clarify to SEH that there was one question of you, very interesting, about Karma in Western places, procedures to erase the bad fruits of mleccha-desha places, in case Hindu overseas, also Bhaaratye, wanna to create something Dharmic. Pandya the Leftist and Green the "one religionist" censored your good question. Sanatani are undecayable and so we are still here. The Seculars are like the other 3 legs of the Bull.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly an answer but a really long comment. Since, it couldn't fit into the comments section, it has been put up as an answer. In my opinion, it is not completely useless, and gives a perspective on shastras.
Temples have built in a lot of places outside India too. Examples are the grand Cambodia temple (the largest in the world), temples in [Japan](https://frontline.thehindu.com/arts-and-culture/heritage/hindu-deities-in-japan/article7654825.ece), a few centuries ago, temples would have been probably present in [Central Asia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ateshgah_of_Baku) too, which was under Hindu rule for long before the Islamic invaders came. You could try to find out about them. The crucial thing to note is that each of these temples is in general different from the ones found in India. They might have certain different design, their own speciality.
According to Rajiv Malhotra, a famous scholar of Hinduism, well respected by in general [various acharyas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-S3kfVgDja0), [ISKCON](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OeHISHyEp4w) and even the [RSS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQJqO8HQTto&list=PLGQElwzyJxtyXHY4Z1JMrdIw4wXXfW5up), Hinduism is not so rigid neither is it so open as to be nothing. It is characterized by what he calls an 'open architecture'. So, it can adapt to new places, new cultures and new conditions, without compromising its core values (unlike, say Islam, which comes packed with Arab culture, or Christianity of any denomination, which comes packed with western values and white culture in general).Accordingly, the rituals and the customs can change with place and time, but what cannot change for it to remain Hindu, are certain cultural values, *such as yamas and niyamas, the adherence to truth, bhramacharya/non-sensuality, self-knowledge, decentralization of power, the ascetic culture of roaming philosophers/sanyasis/brahmanas etc.* ( Italics = my interpretation, these particulars are not mentioned in the book, and if they are, I haven't read them well enough)
Reference: [Being Different: An Indian Challenge to Western Universalism](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13099825-being-different?ac=1&from_search=true&qid=84eKm9yFWS&rank=2), by Rajiv Malhotra.
However, by this, I do not mean at all, that anything can be made into a temple; temple building and the associated effects have their own science associated with them, for example, where the dieties are to be placed, what geometries can the garbha griha support, how many dieties and how many dieties should be present in a particular place, etc. for which the relevant construction manual/ vastu shastras/Shilpa Shastras can be checked. What I do mean, though that it is not so rigid as to be confined to one book. I have read that different shastras were followed in Odisha, and South India, than the shastras which prescribed vimana style architecture which used to be followed in North India (before they were razed down by invaders).They have something that is the core, which must be seperated from the rest of the details. That would be the agreeing parts in the different shastras that relate to temple construction.

Comment: The question is looking for answers from shastras. Not from works of Rajiv Malhotra